# Проблемы с плагином toolTip

Tags: jquery, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/qSYRX/

Решил я написать свой toolTip, и столкнулся с проблемой, мне надо передать в функцию this для каждого объекта (надеюсь правильно выразился). В чем дело?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вы делаете лишние "телодвижения"? Всё [гораздо проще](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qSYRX/1/).

Comment: А если в одном случае надо взять текст из title, в другом задать его самому, а в третьем получить данные через json и обработать их?

Comment: @Fangog, плагин выполняет определенные операции для всех элементов. Можно задать [один новый параметр для всех](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qSYRX/2/), можно и [json-данные передать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qSYRX/4/), но вы даже не представляете, сколько придется учитывать мелких нюансов, ошибка в которых, будет приводить весь ваш "велосипед" в не рабочее состояние.

Comment: http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/
Пример "Loading Flickr Feeds", мне нужно что-то подобное, просто хочу разобраться вот и пишу свой велосипед

Comment: @Fangog, так возьмите и разберите пошагово их плагин. Но не способом "втыка", а разбираясь, что происходит на каждом этапе.